# can any one tell me difference between return true and return false in onLongClickListener in android

Tags: android

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText("ddddddddddddd");
    return true;
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText("ddddddddddddd");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: whenever you get such doubt in future, get the cursor on the method for which you want to get the details and then press `ctrl+q` it will give you most of the explanation you need.

Answer (score 2):

`return true` means you handled it (consumed the long click event), `return false` means you didn't handle it so the event is up for grabs by the next eligible View in line.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) explains this in other words:

> true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

Say your TextView was inside a LinearLayout which also had an OnLongClickListener. If the user long-pressed on the TextView and you returned false, the LinearLayout would receive the event. If you returned true, the LinearLayout would not know about it.

Note, returning true doesn't mean you had to react to the event - you can return true and do nothing to simply consume the event and prevent other Views from knowing about it.

Comment: you can probably give an example of switch case behaviour, code keeps on running unless a break is called. beginners might understand it better.

Comment: it's not similar enough to a switch case to make the comparison.

Comment: i guess it is, just like a particular case is called in switch a long click can be called in a view, just like the code keeps executing for succesive case unless break is called a listener keeps passing to parent views unless true is returned. main aim of this comparison is that many people think that we cannot perform any operations in longclicklistener if we are not returning true,but there might be cases where we need to perform certain operations on particular view before passing it to the parent. Anyways its my perspective of looking this scenario, urs might be different